# Need to extract only one value from a class where more than 2 results while scraping the website using python

Tags: css, python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to extract the whole number in a price while scraping from a website but i am returning 2 values from a class.

**Website Code:**

```
<spani class="a-price-whole">
23
<spani class="a-price-decimal">.</spani>
</spani>
```

**My Scrapy code:**

```
price = response.css('.a-price-whole::text').extract()
```

Let's say, price of a product is `$23.55.`
Expected output is `23`
However, my implementation above returns `23,.` from the code `response.css('.a-price-whole::text').extract()`

Could you please help me the scrapy code to return only the whole number.

Answer (score 1):

```
price = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-price-whole"]/text()').re(r'(\d+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

check the type of the variable price, then convert it to float type before the extract

Comment: I think my question didnt get you. I have a class with whole number and child class with decimal character. I just need the whole number when i call it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use extract_first() instead of extract().

```
price = response.css('.a-price-whole::text').extract_first()
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This will return only one value. But in my case i have n number of products and its prices